# How to Append <a> tag in Angular 4 ternary operator?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am new to angular and ionic. I am having below error in binding   tag in ternary operator.
Unexpected closing tag "a". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("ARGES,appointment.SEQ_NUM)' id='btnPatientPayment' href='javascript:;'>appointment.STATUS[ERROR ->]}}

```
{{ appointment.status !== 'Waiting for Payment' ? appointment.status : "    

a class='btnBlue' (click)='patientpay((appointment.PATIENT_CHARGES === '0' || 

appointment.PATIENT_CHARGES === '') ? appointment.PLAN_COPAY : 

appointment.PATIENT_CHARGES,appointment.SEQ_NUM)' id='btnPatientPayment' 

href='javascript:;'>appointment.TELE_VISIT_STATUS /a  }}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some of your source code?

Comment: this is a tag code <a class='btnBlue' (click)='patientpay((appointment.CHARGES === '0' || appointment.CHARGES === '') ? appointment.PLAN : appointment.CHARGES,appointment.Num)' id='btnPatientPayment' href='javascript:;'>appointment.STATUS</a>

Comment: Post that in the question itself, by editing it, and indenting every line of code by 4 spaces.

Comment: i tried to add it but it is not showing my code

Comment: Because you didn't indent every line of code by 4 spaces as I told you.

Comment: Note to @dynam for later : indenting means add 4 spaces at the *beginning of the line*. It seems you added 4 spaces between words instead. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your anchor tag to this as you are using the same quote all over that's why it is showing some issue. Always try to use `""` for attribute property

```
<a class="btnBlue" (click)="patientpay((appointment.CHARGES === '0' || appointment.CHARGES === '') ? appointment.PLAN : appointment.CHARGES,appointment.Num)" id="btnPatientPayment" href="javascript:;">appointment.STATUS</a>
```

Comment: any other problem you have in angular you can ask.

Comment: yes I have one more problem. Kindly tell me how can i insert above statement in *ngIf e.g <p *ngIf="appointment.status !== 'Waiting for Payment' ? appointment.status : "    

a class='btnBlue' (click)='patientpay((appointment.PATIENT_CHARGES === '0' || 

appointment.PATIENT_CHARGES === '') ? appointment.PLAN_COPAY : 

appointment.PATIENT_CHARGES,appointment.SEQ_NUM)' id='btnPatientPayment' 

href='javascript:;'>appointment.TELE_VISIT_STATUS </a>"></p>

Comment: The problem is you want to use the statement with the ngIf in each case as far as i understand it will return something instead of false which in turn always pass the ngIf condition

Comment: So What should I do then because I have to check conditions to implement it .

Comment: You have to modify your code in such a way if ngif gets true and falue and you can show your result on that basis